# error calculadora android Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "="

Tags: java, android

estoy intentando hacer una calculadora para android studio  ,estoy probando los primeros botones ,pero al momento de clicar el boton de numero en la calculadora esta se cierra . El logcat me marca este error

```
>java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>>Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "="
```

En java el metedo que uso para mostras los numeros en la pantalla es el siguiente

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tvresultado;
float numero1 = 0.0f;
float numero2 = 0.0f;
String operacion ="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvresultado = findViewById(R.id.btnresultado);
    }


public void escribirsiete(View view) {
    float valor = Float.parseFloat(tvresultado.getText().toString());
    if(valor == 0.0f){
        tvresultado.setText("7");
    }else {
        tvresultado.setText(tvresultado.getText() + "7");
    }
}
public void escribirocho(View view) {
    float valor = Float.parseFloat(tvresultado.getText().toString());
    if(valor == 0.0f){
        tvresultado.setText("8");
    }else {
        tvresultado.setText(tvresultado.getText() + "8");
    }
}
```

En android studio tengo configurados los botones asi

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnsiete"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#2196F3"
    android:onClick="escribirsiete"
    android:text="7"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline304"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline102"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline101"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline303" /


<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnocho"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:onClick="escribirocho"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline304"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline103"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/guideline102"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline303" />
```

la pantalla para mostrar los resultados

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvresultado"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
    android:text="0"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="48sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline302"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/guideline301" /
```

Tengo entendido que el problema esta en

```
>Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "="
```

Nose que exactamente a que se refiere ,apenas estoy aprendiendo a programar en android.

Comment: ¿Te sucede al presionar el botón por primera vez?

Comment: asi es ,no puedo introducir el primer numero porque se cierra la app,sucede con todos los botones de numero.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir toda la clase y todo el layout de la actividad? Es que se me hace que el problema no va por lo que muestras

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a el error:

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "="

tratas de convertir un valor que no es numerico como lo es "=" a `Float` lo cual no es posible, por esta razón obtienes el error `NumberFormatException`.

Puedes usar un método para validar, en caso de error retorna el valor de 0.0:

```
public static float getFloatFromString(String valor) {
    float d = 0.0f;
    try {
         d = Float.parseFloat(valor);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return d;
    }
    return d;
 }
```

Lo llamarías de esta forma:

```
public void escribirsiete(View view) {
    float valor = getFloatFromString(tvresultado.getText().toString());
    if(valor == 0.0f){
        tvresultado.setText("7");
    }else {
        tvresultado.setText(tvresultado.getText() + "7");
    }
}


public void escribirocho(View view) {
    float valor = getFloatFromString(tvresultado.getText().toString());
    if(valor == 0.0f){
        tvresultado.setText("8");
    }else {
        tvresultado.setText(tvresultado.getText() + "8");
    }
}
```